# Way to find the remainder of two function, but the divisor is irreducible. ($f(x)$ divided by $g(x)$, but $g(x)$ is irreducible.)

Tags: functions, polynomials

Follow by my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3492047/642089), which is solved by the Little Bézout's theorem, they factored the function $g(x)$ and use its root. Now, I wonder, what if $g(x)$ is irreducible ? How do we solve it?

Comment: diviion of polynonials by a  equivalent of long division...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, one can always use [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) to divide the polynomials. Thus, we are theoretically done as we know an algorithm to compute it.

Another thing that one can note is that polynomials will factor if we allow complex factors. So if we can compute those, then the problem gets simplified once again.

For example, if we want to divide $f(x) = x^{100} - x^{49}$ by $g(x) = x^4 - 1$, we can once again write $f(x) = g(x)q(x) + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ and substitute $x = \pm i, \pm 1$ to get values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

Comment: What if... $f(x)$ is so large that it is impossible to use the polynomial long division to divide, and  $g(x)$ is a function have $deg$ greater than $5$?

Comment: How can a polynomial be "so large that it is impossible to use the polynomial long division to divide"? The method does not assume anything about the size of $f$ and works for all polynomials. And yes, the second method I said is helpful only if you can actually factor the polynomial yourself. (Note that even if degree is ≥5, it still is possible for the polynomial to be factorisable.)

Comment: For example, some quintic equations are not solvable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Finding_roots_of_a_quintic_equation
Also, function like $f(x)=x^{2020}-3x^{2019}+9x^2+1$ or something like that

Comment: Yes, but even in those cases, we can always rely on polynomial long division.